# How can I resolve OutOfMemory Error from gradle build?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "ConnnectionExpirer"

*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message can't create name string at ./src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 827


Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "ExpirationReaper-0-Fetch"
```

In my gradle.properties
**org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx8G -XX:MaxPermSize=2024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8**

My gradle distribution is **gradle-6.4.1**

I recently included many integration tests in my code after which I started seeing this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It's Gradle feature. If you'll open your task manager, you can see the java process (Gradle daemon), which takes up more and more memory with each of run your tests. When you'll open Gradle log files you can see a lot of errors `"Connection timeout"`. I'm reading comments other people and they write - it's a bug.
So, if you use `IntelliJ IDEA` there is a plugin with the name `"Easy Gradle"` with the command `Gradle Kill`. I use it. It kills Gradle's daemon.

see more [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html)